# Remove json lines based on specific string

Tags: python, json, python-2.7

I have a `json` file that reads something like this:

```
[{"headline":"Ntugamo court issues criminal summons against Rukutana",
"url_src":"\/news\/headlines\/67240-ntugamo-court-issues-criminal-summons-against-rukutana"},
{"headline":"Corruption: Equal Opportunities Commission boss granted bail",
"url_src":"\/news\/headlines\/67239-corruption-equal-opportunities-commission-boss-granted-bail"},
{"headline":"Bobi Wine to launch corruption manifesto in Mbarara rejects EC security team",
"url_src":"https:\/\/www.monitor.co.ug"}]
```

I am trying to find and remove all the sections within `{` and `}` that contain the word Corruption, including the curly brackets themselves.

For example, in this case the .py script would remove

```
{"headline":"Corruption: Equal Opportunities Commission boss granted bail",
```

"url_src":"/news/headlines/67239-corruption-equal-opportunities-commission-boss-granted-bail"}

and also remove

```
{"headline":"Bobi Wine to launch corruption manifesto in Mbarara rejects EC security team","url_src":"https:\/\/www.monitor.co.ug"}
```

Is this possible with Python 2.7?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) to iterate through each `dict` in the `list`.

Convert each dictionary into a string in each iteration, and use `if "corruption" not in str(d).lower()` to check to see if the string `"corruption"` is in the lowercased string. If not, then keep it:

```
import json

with open("j.json", "rb") as f:
    lst = json.load(f)

lst = [d for d in lst if "corruption" not in str(d).lower()]

print(lst)
```

Output:

```
[{'headline': 'Ntugamo court issues criminal summons against Rukutana',
  'url_src': '/news/headlines/67240-ntugamo-court-issues-criminal-summons-against-rukutana'}]
```

If you want to write the list back into the `json` file, use `json.dump`:

```
with open("j.json", "w", encoding="utf8") as f:
    json.dump(lst, f)
```